# Vutify list group make parent clickable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to make the parent, in the case courses clickable, without toggling the course items below on/off and only have the arrow, to the right, show/hide the child items. At the moment I have just added a router link to the parent item in the list if it has a path.

[image: menu]

```
      <v-list-group
        v-if="item.children"
        v-model="item.active"
        :key="item.title"
        :prepend-icon="item.icon"
         style="border-top: solid; border-color: #004d3d; border-width: thin;"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title class="text">
                <router-link v-if="item.path" :to="item.path">{{ item.text }}</router-link>
                <span v-else>{{ item.text }}</span>
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </template>

        <template v-for="child in item.children">
          <v-list-item
            :key="child.title"
            :to="child.path"
            v-if="$store.getters['session/hasPermissionKey'](child.permissionKey)"
          >
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-icon>{{ child.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title class="text">
                {{ child.title }}
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-list-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I actually did something similar with expansion panels recently.

What I needed to do was to allow the expansion panel header to be clickable while only expanding the panel using the icon.

To do this, I bound `@click.stop="myMethod` instead of `@click`

The `.stop` modifier prevents the click event from the component from bubbling up.

This is not to be confused with the `.prevent` modifier which is used to prevent the default browser behaviour (like a form submit or reload) from occurring.

You'll still need to bind the activators to the icon itself though, or a `@click.stop` method on the icon to toggle opening and closing the children.

Comment: Cheers that has done it. I created the method it checks the text value if it is courses it does nothing, if it is anything else then the active value is set to true/false

Comment: Perfect :) Glad this helped you out. Best of luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

As i had the same problem myself and did not find it too intuitive at first how to get this together i just want to add a small snippet how the wished element & behavior look in a few lines of code, to make it easier to comprehend for others:

```
<v-list-group value="Courses" prepend-icon="mdi-view-list">
  <template v-slot:activator="{isOpen, props}">
    <v-list-item
       title="Courses"
       @click="router.push(FILL_ME_IN)"
    >
      <template v-slot:append>
        <v-icon
          v-bind="props"
          :icon="isOpen?'mdi-chevron-up':'mdi-chevron-down'"
        />
      </template>

    </v-list-item>
  </template>
  ...
 </v-list-group>
```