# don't expand v-list-group if click on v-checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have an expandable `v-list-group` with a `v-checkbox` where when i click on the v-checkbox the list toggles. I want to disable this reaction. it is possible? my code element:

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-group>
        <template v-slot:activator>
            <v-list-item-action>
                <v-checkbox @click="fn()"/>
            </v-list-item-action>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title/>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </template>
        ...
    </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `click.stop` on the v-checkbox in order to stop click event propagation.

- **Reference**: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on
- **Similar question**: [Vutify list group make parent clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66973790/vutify-list-group-make-parent-clickable)